# Using LazZiya ExpressLocalization Nuget package to Localize web app

Tags: c#, localization, nuget-package, resx, lazziya.expresslocalization

I have been trying to follow these two tutorials to add Localization to my .Net Core Razor web app.

http://ziyad.info/en/articles/36-Develop_Multi_Cultural_Web_Application_Using_ExpressLocalization

https://medium.com/swlh/step-by-step-tutorial-to-build-multi-cultural-asp-net-core-web-app-3fac9a960c43

I have tried creating projects from scratch. I have tried adding to my existing projects. I have tried using the *LocalizeTagHelper* and *SharedCultureLocalizer* options without success.

I just cant get any text such as '**Home**' or '**myApp**' below to change.

When I select a language in my dropdown, the language is specified in the URL (See below), but my text just wont change.

**Dropdown component & Home text x 2:**

[image]

**Url:**

[image]

**My Packages:**
[image]

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using LazZiya.ExpressLocalization
@inject ISharedCultureLocalizer _loc

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @_loc["myApp"];
}

    <body>
        <h1 class="display-4" localize-content>Home</h1>
        <header>
            <div class="bg-img">
                <div class="container-title">
                    <div class="block-title block-title1">
                        <language-nav cookie-handler-url="@Url.Page("/Index", "SetCultureCookie", new { area="", cltr="{0}", returnUrl="{1}" })"></language-nav>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-title block-title2 d-none d-md-block d-lg-block d-xl-block"><img src="/image/title_image.png" class="img-fluid"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="row_primary">
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace myApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public IActionResult OnGetSetCultureCookie(string cltr, string returnUrl)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(cltr)),
                new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
            );

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using LazZiya.ExpressLocalization;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using myApp.wwwroot.LocalizationResources;

namespace myApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();

            var cultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("de"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
            };
            services.AddRazorPages().AddExpressLocalization<ExpressLocalizationResource, ViewLocalizationResource >( ops =>
                {
                    ops.ResourcesPath = "LocalizationResources";
                    ops.RequestLocalizationOptions = o =>
                    {
                        o.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                        o.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
                        o.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                    };
                });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseRequestLocalization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**wwwroot**

[image]

**resx example**

[image]

**resx properties**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My resx file had its Build Action property as 'Content' instead of '**Embedded Resource**'.
And my LocSource.cs had its Build Action property as 'Embedded Resource' instead of '**C# compiler**'.

Really looking forward to using this package now, looks like it will make life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [V4.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LazZiya.ExpressLocalization/) you don't need `LazZiya.TagHelpers.Localization`, just uninstall it because the `LocalizeTagHelper` has been moved to `LazZiya.ExpressLocalization` in the latest version.

So, just add the localize taghelper to `_ViewImports.cshtml` as below:

```
@addTagHelper *, LazZiya.ExpressLocalization
```

And change the access modifier of the strings in the resource file to **No code generation**:

[image]

More details can be found in [ExpressLocalization wiki](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/wiki)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I appreciate the help. I'm trying to walk through the wiki implementation. On the page below, where am I supposed to "Setup ExpressLocalization to use one resource file:" ? I have created the LocSource.cs file in my LocalizationResources folder and added the code to the Startup.cs file, but it is throwing a null pointer exception in the browser when I start the app.

services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddExpressLocalization<LocSource>(ops => 
    {
        /* options */
    });

https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/wiki/One-Resource-File

Comment: @DMur Let's follow the issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/LazZiya/ExpressLocalization/issues/19) then we can mention the right steps here for future reference...